# Bone selection hidden in side view

Tags: armature, rigify, visibility

I am using Rigify and created an armature. If I select anything on the left side of the body (arm or leg bones) thee selection is not visible in the side/right view. What could cause this? I tried selecting all, hiding and then unhiding all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Strange.  Would expect to see Thigh.L in right ortho, but not Thigh.R as it is perfectly obscured by Thigh.L.

Comment: And curiously, the bone is not visible in both left and right views (@batFINGER)

Comment: It is the same in front/back... I guess (just a guess), there is no z for bones drawing in wireframe mode...? The behavior seems to be: the last created is drawn over

Comment: It is visible in front or back, but not left or right.

Comment: @BenMora, I meant, if you rotate so that they are front back: same thing

Comment: @lemon, to your second comment, it seems it's not related to that because even when I move the bone in right or left side view it still does not appear selected even when nothing is in front of it.

Comment: Oh, wait. I'm not sure what I did, but that isn't the case anymore. I can now see it when moving. Weird. It definitely was not visible when moved earlier.

Comment: And this is the same for meshes... just try: create a cube, select an edge on the right (you right) and see

Comment: Have a look at this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyDvh.gif

Comment: Figured it out. I had X-Axis Mirror on, so the one showing in front of it always shows in front. That was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Following the question, its comments and the answer from the OP, my though is this is not the axis mirror which leads to the situation (or please @BenMora explain a bit more).

Here is a setting with an operator derived from the script templates.

It's showing in blue the faces index, in green edges index and in red the index of vertices. We are here in face selection mode, but the same occurs whatever the mode is.

[image]

Element's index is a way to identify it in the mesh. To be simple, it is an integer designing the element (in a separated range for vertices, edges and faces).

What is happening here (experimental conclusions):

In wireframe mode, Blender draws following the index. So bigger index is drawn over the smaller one.

And this is visibly the same for armatures.

To tell the truth, before this question, I've never noticed it... but thinking about it, I'm quite sure this is a wanted behavior for performance reason... maybe.

Please comment if this is to report to the Foundation in the bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I had "X-Axis Mirror" turned on, so when I moved bones the mirrored one constantly displayed in front of it. @lemon pointed out that the order in which the bones were created is factored when determining which to draw.