# ShrinkWrap mesh with hole around another mesh with hole

Tags: modifiers

I want to morph a mesh into another, using shrinkwrap modifier. See below in the scripture; my goal is to morph the half cricle into the triangle:

[image: Meshes for morphing 1]

So I added a shrink wrap modifier to the half circle mesh and choosed the triangle as the target.

It's not quite perfect with basic settings of the modifier. So I tried to tweak it by scaling the half circle in edit mode:

[image: Meshes for morphing 4]

But it's even worst...

I've tried to move vertex one by one, but I gave up as it's very difficult; I've also tried to play with all the settings of the modifier, but I can't get the result I want.

So I'm asking for help to discover how I can perform that morphing. Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: Have you considered using shape keys instead of shrinkwrap?

Comment: Shrinkwrap works well to project smaller shapes into a larger surface, it is never going to work well for morphing two characters. As cegaton suggested might be better to look into shapekeys

Comment: Yes I've tried shape keys with "join as shapes" option. But the result is a total mess...
Maybe I use it not the right way. Do you have any advice to do it with shapekeys?

Comment: For shape key joining, you need at least three things: same amount of vertices, same order (in internal data), same corresponding faces.

Comment: I have the same number of vertices on each mesh, but it's the first time I hear about the same order. I'm going to google that.

While I'm doing some search, can you check my blend file and tell me if it meets the conditions that you said?

>>> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0e6n1XhjXoGT1pRXzRReU1zUnM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @stephane, they are not. The code in the blend file linked in this question can help to see all indices (vertices, edges, polygons) https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76131/modal-operator-and-opengl-drawing-update-issue. For your question, I'd say the answer may depend: do you want a solution for this particular meshes or a more general one?

Comment: lemmon, thanks! I'm going to visit that link. To answer your question: both! :)
I want to solve my problem with these particular meshes but I also want to be able to do it for any other case.