# How do I display a variable (say elapsed time) in the 3d window?

Tags: python, 3d-view

Beginner here: I know how to display a text string but don't want a fixed value but would like it to display a time varying output from my python script which executes with  scripted time.sleep() timers. (I am not using the timeline).

Comment: This is a question only but the attached file contains code to display texts with opengl https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76131/modal-operator-and-opengl-drawing-update-issue

Comment: Possibly related (since it creates text objects and positions them in the scene) : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101485/29586

Comment: [Also possibly related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89375/how-can-i-create-a-countdown-timer-in-cycles)   Wouldn't recommend using `time.sleep` in blender, rather use a modal timer operator. There is one in the scripting templates. [See this Q / A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95335/time-delay-when-selecting-objects-in-a-python-script)  Or given the application is designed to animate, use the timeline.